# Excel Conditional sum on same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a rather basic Excel question, but my Excel skills suck.

What I want is a conditional sum, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Example:

```
       A     B     C     D     E
    -------------------------------
1   |  X  |     |     |     |  1  |     
    -------------------------------
2   |     |     |     |     |  2  |     
    -------------------------------
3   |  X  |     |     |     |  4  |     
    -------------------------------
4   |     |     |     | res |  5  |     
    -------------------------------
```

I want E4 to have the sum of the previous values on the E column IF there is an X on the column A on the same row.
So result = 1 + 4
If there was an X on A2, result would be = 1 + 2 + 4

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SUMIF` function does a conditional sum based on values in another range, e.g. for your example you can use this formula in E4

`=SUMIF(A1:A3,"X",E1:E3)`